# Solving concurrency problems in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I was asked this question in a technical test recently, and have been wondering what would be a good answer, in case it comes up again.

Basically, given a scenario in which several race conditions have been found in JSP (due to extensive usage of instance variables and scriptlet code), what would be a good way to resolve the concurrency issues arising, without rewriting the code?

I  answered along the lines of: making use of Spring beans to access the instance variables, so as to avoid multiple objects being created while accessing variables (since Spring beans are singleton in design, by default). I am keen to hear other interpretations or answers though.

Comment: Maybe this is jsp specific - but I have never heard of Java beans being singletons by design?!

Comment: My answer would be "There would be no good way to resolve the concurrency issues arising, without rewriting the code". Your answer doesn't make much sense: 1. using java beans is rewriting the code; 2. java beans are not singletons; 3. using singletons don't solve concurrency issues. 4. If they did, there would be no concurrency issue in the JSP, since a JSP is a singleton

Comment: @GhostCat: sorry I meant Spring beans! Have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a JSP is requested for the first time or when the web app starts up, the servlet container will compile it into a class extending `HttpServlet` and use it during the web app's lifetime ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)).

JSP have a *Page Directive Attributes*. You can check it in the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/)

Specifically, there is a attribute that you can change on the page:

```
<%@ page isThreadSafe="false" %>
```

This attribute indicates the level of thread safety implemented in the page.

- If `false` then the JSP container shall dispatch multiple outstanding
  client requests, one at a time, in the order they were received, to
  the page implementation for processing.
- If `true` then the JSP container may choose to dispatch multiple outstanding client requests to the page simultaneously.

Page authors using `true` must ensure that they properly
synchronize access to the shared state of the page.
Default is `true`.
Note that even if the `isThreadSafe` attribute is `false` the JSP
page author must ensure that accesses to any shared objects
are properly synchronized. The objects may be shared in
either the `ServletContext` or the `HttpSession`.

So, if you set the `isThreadSafe` attribute to `false` (thus that the resulting servlet should implement the `SingleThreadModel`) and you make sure that your scriplet do not use objects that shared in either the `ServletContext` or the `HttpSession`, then it may be a good way to resolve the concurrency issues.

Comment: Note: `SingleThreadModel` has been deprecated since Servlet 2.4 and is being removed in Servlet 6.0.  This removal makes JSP's `isThreadSafe` directive a no-op.